# Sending form to another view django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am building a website and I want various views that will ask the user to request a quote from our page. I want to keep the code as DRY as possible so I am writing a view `quote` which will receive the quote requests from various views and, if there is a validation error redirect back to the page that made the request. I managed to solve this using the super bad practice 'global variables'. I need a better solution, I would like redirecting to respective view with the current form so I can iterate through the `form.errors`. Here is my code:

```
def send_quote(request):
    form = Quote(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # do stuff when valid
        return redirect('Support:thanks', name=name or None)
    quote_for = request.POST['for_what']
    global session_form
    session_form = form
    return redirect('Main:' + quote_for) # Here I would like to send form instead of storing in global variable`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HttpResponseRedirect function, and pass as argument the page that made the request.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

All the META data is store on a dictionary, if you want to learn more check the documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: I tried with that and it does redirect to the last page that sent the request, but is the form still available after redirection?

Comment: `HttpResponseRedirect` is a class.

Comment: You could use a session to store the form, and the page you redirect will handle it properly.

Comment: Glad I could help you! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect to the referrer, `form.errors` will be empty, as redirection is always a GET request.

I can think of two solutions to your problem:

1. Submit forms asynchronously using JavaScript and so populate the errors
2. Make all the views containing the form support POST - one way to do this would be to create a base class that inherits from [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView)

The second option is a typical way of handling forms in Django - you process both POST and GET inside the same view.

Answer (score -1):

After two days of searching I finally found the answer. Instead of saving `form` in `request.session` I just save `request.POST` and then redirect. Here is the code:

```
def send_quote(request):
    form = Quote(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # do stuff when valid
        return redirect('Support:thanks', name=name or None)
    quote_for = request.POST['for_what']
    request.session['invalid_form'] = request.POST
    return redirect('Main:endview')

def endview(request):
    session_form = request.session.pop('invalid_form', False)
    if session_form:
        form = Quote(session_form)
        # render template again with invalid form ;)
```

Now I can repeat this with all the views I want and just change the `what_for` input of each form to match the respective view (Like I intended).

Comment: This will not work as expected if your users use more than one browser tab.

Comment: I am just saving in session for the time it takes to redirect. After redirection I am removing the value from the session completely so, unless the user has access to my server and is able to add a breakpoint it will work as expected